# Continuous Monitoring Client Socket Connection in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am using Client-Server programming in java .
How can i get notified when a client lost his internet connection . So that i can free that Port for another user.

I get client request As :

```
readerIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
readerIn.readLine();
```

So here my code waits for client message for infinite time while he has lost his internet connection. I need to check for his net connection in background. Please Help

Thanks

Comment: create a new thread which one will work in background

Comment: How did you handle SocketException?

Answer (score 0):

No need for anything 'in background'. Just set a reasonable read timeout with `Socket.setSoTimeout(),` and handle the resulting `SocketTimeoutException` by closing the socket and exiting the thread.

Answer (score -1):

An option is to try NIO socket programming. A random (googl'd) quick tutorial [here](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/l).

It's a little involved, but the code structure is robust and you can easily expand it to fit your needs.

Comment: `Socket.isConnected()` doesn't magically become false when the peer becomes disconnected. It tells you whether you ever connected the `Socket`. It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the connection. Also concurrent closing isn't defined for `java.io` or `java.net` classes. Also this loop never sleeps so it will smoke the CPU. -1

Comment: I read the doc for isConnected. You're right :) Removed faulty code and posted a better tutorial.